# Passing env variables to gatsby build or serve in macOS (or linux)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I followed the instructions for [additional environment](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#additional-environments-staging-test-etc) in Gatsby.

It works with command `gatsby develop`, but when I am using the same for `gatsby build` command, I see that it uses `.env.production` and not `.env.staging` parameters

```
export ACTIVE_ENV=staging npm run build
```

gatsby.config file:

```
let activeEnv =
  process.env.ACTIVE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"

console.log(`Using environment config: '${activeEnv}'`)

require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${activeEnv}`,
})
```

It would print that it uses staging env, but the variables in the .js files will be taken from .env.production.

What is wrong?